# XenServer 6.2 IPv6 routing

Tags: linux, routing, ipv6, xenserver

I'm having trouble setting up a new server (hosted at "hetzner") with latest XenServer 6.2.
IPv4 is working fine, but I'm stuck at IPv6 Setup.
What I got so far:

**xen**:

```
 $> ip -6 addr
 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436
     inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 3: xenbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500
     inet6 2a01:4f8:xxx:yyyy::2/112 scope global
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 $> ip -6 route
 unreachable ::/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 0
 unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 0
  [...]
 2a01:4f8:xxx:yyy::/112 dev xenbr0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
 unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 0
 fe80::1 dev xenbr0  metric 1024  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
 fe80::/64 dev xenbr0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
 ff00::/8 dev xenbr0  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
 default via fe80::1 dev xenbr0  metric 1024  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0

 $> ping6 google.de
 64 bytes from fra07s29-in-x17.1e100.net: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=9.68 ms
```

also: firewall disabled.

**VM** (CentOS6):

```
 $> ip -6 addr
 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436
     inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
     inet6 2a01:4f8:xxx:yyy::3/64 scope global
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 $> ip -6 route
 unreachable ::/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
 unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
 [...]
 default via 2a01:4f8:xxx:yyyy::2 dev eth0  metric 1024  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295

 $> ping6 google.de
 From 2a01:4f8:xxx:yyyy::2 icmp_seq=10 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
 $> ping 2a01:4f8:xxx:yyy::2
 64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:xxx:yyyy::2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.15 ms
```

Firewall also disabled on this guest.

I followed the howto at http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Citrix_XenServer/en#IPv6 and did all the mentioned steps and tried with different guests. My assigned IPv6-subnet is 2a01:4f8:xxx:yyyy::/64 and my IPv6-Gateway is fe80::1

Any help and further tips for diagnosis is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I just found the solution myself:

Though the ISPs wiki tells me to add the first IPv6 as default gateway, setting it to fe80::1 works fine.

I deleted the default route and added a new one like this:

```
 ip route add default via fe80::1 dev eth0
```

Connection works both ways - incoming and outgoing ipv6.

This is now my guest configuration of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:

```
 IPV6INIT="yes"
 IPV6_DEFAULTGW="fe80::1"
 IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=eth0
 IPV6ADDR="2a01:4f8:xxx:yyyy::3/64"
```

I have not much knowledge of IPv6 yet, so I don't know what exactly happened here and if it is the right solution, but it works.

Comment: Keep in mind that Hetzner's network setup is very non-standard. Don't try to apply this knowledge elsewhere.